# Spyder Trace Debugging - Python

Tags: python, debugging, runtime-error, spyder, traceback

I am having a weird situation where the trace for an AttributeError keeps referencing the exact same absolute line number in my code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-59-513669e63f3e>", line 4, in <module>
    "line of code being run"

  File "modulepath", line 148, in "method that contains the line of code"
    "content of the line causing the error"

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'attribute_name'
```

If I make line 148 empty (by putting in new lines, etc.) or if I put a comment on line 148, the trace keeps pointing to line 148 as the source of the error.

I am having trouble debugging this particular error in general since I am (to the best of my knowledge) not using that particular attribute on any list object in my code (but it seems to indicate that I'm doing so). I will figure out that issue on my own. My main question is: what causes Spyder to repeatedly reference the exact same absolute line number in a traceback? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, use a fresh new console - that worked for me.